# How to create production stability drupal 8 project using composer?

Tags: drupal, composer-php, drupal-8

I've been getting to drupal and recently found out about composer. I use the following command to create a dev drupal instance:

```
composer create-project drupal-composer/drupal-project:~8.x-dev <folder-name> --stability dev --no-interaction
```

I was wondering what the package name is for the stable release of drupal.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need to change anything about your core build, both development and production will be running the current build of `drupal/core`. But modules like Devel or Stage File Proxy can be added to the `require-dev` section in your composer.json and installed while doing development and kept out of the build on production.

Hopefully this link will help: https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/update/update-core-via-composer#update-drupal-8-core

The very last part about Production environments says to run `composer install --no-dev` to remove any dev dependencies from the build.